# Value changing when assigned to variable

Tags: php, phpunit, variable-assignment, bit, endianness

I am writting a programm to decode a binary file. I am currently in test phase and I use phpunit. I tried to assign a two byte value into a variable but the value changed without any apparent reason. I get 132 instead of 1.

The original bytes of the file are : 00 0F 00 01

Here is the code who decodes this part :

```
$infos = unpack('n2', fread($file, 4));
print_r($infos);
print($infos[2]);
$nb = $infos[2];
print(' nb '.$nb);
```

here is the result in the console :
Array
(
[1] => 15
[2] => 1
)
1 nb 132

The contents of $infos are completely fine, but I don't understand why $nb takes the value 132.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code from a file populated with your 4 bytes and the result I get is

**Array ( [1] => 15 [2] => 1 ) 1 nb 1**

The only thing I can think of is that there might be a Byte order mark (BOM) in your file that is interfering with things.

Does your file have any special character encodings?

Your code is good so I think it's the file at fault

Comment: The file is a bin file created by a program in java. Can this be the origin of the problem ?

Comment: It could be the problem. Some files contain special hidden characters at the beginning of the file called Byte order markers that can interfere with things. Without actually seeing your file I can't say for sure. Can you look at the file in with a hex editor? You should see 00 0F 00 01 as the first 4 characters.

Comment: The file doesn't have any of those specials caracters (exept if I accidentally created them by dumb chance). The file doesn't have any unexpected bytes. 00 0F 00 01 are not the first bytes, but they are exactly where I expected them. I don't think the file is at fault.

Comment: what's the output from:  echo " nb '$nb'";